# which method of http is best in android?

Tags: android, multithreading, http, connection

i have 2 method to download a picture from internet , result is a inputstream .
but one of this will make the download image fail , i don't know why ,
here is the code of have a bug :

```
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet(imageName);
            HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpClient.execute(get);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity); 
            InputStream is = bufHttpEntity.getContent();
```

this is another one that i am using :

```
        URL imageUrl = new URL(imageName);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl
                .openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
```

i am wonder if any one can tell me 
1. why i use method 1 to get a inputstram , that can not show a picture
2. i have seen some one say that use a httpclient , don't use connection . i don't know the reason ?? is connection is worse that http client ??

i am use in a multithread ecvironment, method two work normal , but method one can't .

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Bitmap getimage(String imageUrl) {

        Log.i("imageurl", imageUrl);
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        BufferedInputStream bis = null;
        InputStream is = null;

        try {
            String url = imageUrl;
            URL myUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myUrl.openConnection();

            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.connect();
            if (conn.getResponseCode() != 404) {
                is = conn.getInputStream();
                bis = new BufferedInputStream(is, 8192);
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);

            }
            conn.disconnect();

        }catch (Exception e) {
             Log.e("getImageData", e.toString());
             return bitmap;
        }
        finally{
            if (bis != null) 
            {
                try{
                    bis.close();
                }catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (is != null) 
            {
                try {
                    is.close();
                }catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
         return bitmap;
    }
```

Comment: use bufferedinputstream is better ??